# Regex to globally accept back space in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, currency

I've got this regex that I'm using to restrict currency fields and it works great because I can simply replace the . with a , and I can easily localize it on the fly. My only issues is I can't seem to delete the last remaining character using this regex and I would like to be able to do that. is there a way to modify this regex to allow that?

```
^[+-]?([\b0-9])+[.]?([0-9])+$
```

EDIT: The regex above is being passed as a string through props in react to an input field. The input field is then checking this method before updating its value

```
  matchRegex = (reg, val) => {
const regex = new RegExp(reg, "gm");
if (regex.test(val)) {
  return true;
}
return false;
```

};

Comment: I think you need to show what you are doing with that reg exp

Comment: If you're trying to delete the last character, why use regex? Why not just use something like `str.slice(0,str.length-1)`

Comment: I'm trying to intercept the incoming keystroke and either allow or disallow it. That's why I'm using regex. However, once I backspace to the last character, I'm unable to delete it as well if need be. That's where the issue is.

Comment: try doing event.preventDefault() by using the event in keystroke handler

Comment: @CognitiveDesire could you please clarify and/or provide an example.

Comment: Make a fiddle and I will try to change it

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to figure this one out. Since I'm intercepting the keystrokes, I actually don't need to worry about the whole string and can focus on one input character at a time so the following was able to meet my needs:

```
^([\b^0-9.-])*$
```